# AWS APIGateway From route53 only

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I am using route53 to call api gateway (custom domain names used). API gateway can still be accessed using it's invoke public URL.

Is there any way to block access via public URL.
Can resource policy used for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a page about it in documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/rest-api-disable-default-endpoint.html